# Heroku Connect, detect salesforce update in postgres

Tags: postgresql, heroku, salesforce, heroku-postgres, heroku-connect

So I have an app taking advantages of Heroku Connect to sync datas between platforms.
I need to find a way to detect when an update has been made by Salesforce (or at least, when the sync has been executed). I'm using sequelize in nodejs, but of course the hooks don't work since heroku connect works directly on the DB and doesn't use the ORM.
So I'm wondering what are my options here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solutions that come to my mind (likely there are more):

1. check out the [Heroku Connect system tables](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-connect-database-tables#system-tables) like `_trigger_log`. This table will give you an exact log of the actions HC took (updates/insert/deletes) with information about the record. Yes, you would need to poll it :)
2. Postgres brings it's own queue-system with `LISTEN` and `NOTIFY`. You an write your own database-trigger that will react on change in the salesforce tables, and have a listening/worker-process on the `LISTEN` queue in PostgreSQL.

Comment: We ended up using the second solution, but we had to use version 6.0 of pg, because the 7 doesn't seem to have .on('notifications') anymore. But it's working like a charm now !